# Node JS slow script execution on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, terminal

Here is an issue:

I have a script file **javascript.js**

```
console.time("js");
console.log(1+1);
console.timeEnd("js");
```

Execution with command: `time node javascript.js`
will print this output:

```
2
js: 7.355ms

real    0m1,147s
user    0m1,102s
sys 0m0,045s
```

Js code execution takes 7ms, but results in the terminal will be after 1 second.

Same is for this commad: `time prettier -v`

```
time prettier -v
2.2.1

real    0m1,763s
user    0m1,666s
sys 0m0,040s
```

How to fix this 1 second issue? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

PS: For an example if i will run php script in terminal there is no 1 second delay

```
time php php.php
2

real    0m0,029s
user    0m0,016s
sys 0m0,009s
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like Node.js takes a longer time to start up than PHP. Will you be starting so many Node.js processes that the startup delay is an issue? If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thaks, but my goal is to fix this issue. I want to see results immediately.

Comment: Then you'll probably want to `ptrace` or otherwise profile `node` to see what it's spending its time on starting up and figure out how to start making it faster. It'll be a long road :)

Comment: In a `node:16-buster` Docker container on my Macbook, I get `js: 7.146ms, 
real 0m0.045s, user 0m0.022s, sys 0m0.019s`. There may be something off with your setup. Is e.g. `node` provided by `nvm` or some other Bash script wrapper?

Comment: I've just updated nodejs to v16 and everything is fine now